# Taking screenshots with Selenium Builder

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using [Selenium Builder](http://sebuilder.github.io/se-builder), I've created the following json file:

```
{
  "type": "script",
  "seleniumVersion": "2",
  "formatVersion": 2,
  "steps": [
    {
      "type": "get",
      "url": "http://stackoverflow.com/"
    },
    {
      "type": "saveScreenshot",
      "file": foo.png"
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "configs": {},
    "source": "none"
  },
  "inputs": [],
  "timeoutSeconds": 60
}
```

I tried running it on Windows 7 and two different Ubuntu machines. Instead of the filepath "foo.png" I had also inserted "E:\foo.png" / "/home/swege/foo.png". However, I always get the "exception":

```
Could not take screenshot of current page - [object Object]
```

At least I would like to be able to read the "error object", but every system just puts out that the error is a JavaScript object. Any idea how to fix the issue or read the full error message?

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

http://www.ontestautomation.com/how-to-create-screenshots-in-your-selenium-webdriver-tests/

Above can help you to get exact code that how you can take screenshots using selenium.

Answer (score 0):

So I pulled down and looked at the source for Selenium Builder 2 and found two files that I think show the origin of the error, command_processor.js and driver_component.js.

I can't make out why the error is occurring - maybe someone here can build on this?

Comment: thanks. strictly speaking, this is not an answer. would look better as a comment

Comment: My apologies - I don't have enough reputation to comment on questions.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an answer for now - the one below by Quality-Expert refers to writing your own code. Using Webdriver, not Selenium Builder. The reason I use it is because my programming isn't that advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a full file path, not just `foo.png`. On Mac, these worked for me: `~/foo.png` and `~/Downloads/screenshots/foo.png`.

It's also important that the folder exists and is writable by the account running the web browser.